# let T be a Tree with at least k edges, $K \geq 2$. then how many connected components are there in a subgraph of T obtained by deleting k edges in T

Tags: graph-theory

I cannot understand the question properly.

If T is a tree with K edges then it will have K+1 Vertices and deleting K edges will give K+1 components.

Is this true?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The question states that the graph has **at least** $k$ edges. For example a tree on 1000 vertices has in particular at least two edges. Your observation that there will be $k+1$ components remains true, although there is something to prove now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first property can be found pretty much anywhere (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)).

For the second one, it isn't that well phrased as is, it is obvious that removing the $K$ edges from a graph with $K+1$ vertices will disconnect all the vertices and yield $K+1$ connected components.

The interesting statement is rather that removing $K$ edges from any tree with more than $K$ edges yields $K+1$ connected components. Let us prove this by induction on the number of edges deleted, for such a tree.

- Removing one edge from any tree disconnects it (otherwise we would have a cycle) and yields two connected components.
- Now, assume the result holds up until $K$ edges. Take any $K+1$ edges that you want to remove, you know removing the first $K$ will yield $K+1$ connected components by induction. Consider the last edge to remove, $e$, it must belong to one of the $K+1$ connected components obtained after the first $K$ deletions. Now, removing $e$ from the connected component it belongs to will split the component into two connected components (this is the base case of the induction), and it will not disconnect the other $K$ connected components. So we end up with the untouched $K$ components, plus the new two stemming from the one that $e$ was in, thus $K+2$ of them, finishing the induction.